# Calc of max, or max of calc in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to do something like this

```
max-width: calc(max(500px, 100% - 80px))
```

or

```
max-width: max(500px, calc(100% - 80px)))
```

in CSS?

Comment: Have you tried them out yourself?

Comment: As @gert-sønderby said, just use these two: min-width:500px; width:calc(100% - 80px);

Comment: some time you don't know which one is bigger. is 500px bigger or calc(100% - 80px) bigger ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[`min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min), [`max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max), and [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) are finally available!

Support starts in Firefox 75, Chrome 79, and Safari 11.1 (`clamp` is available in Safari 13.1).

`min()` and `max()` take any number of arguments.

`clamp()` has syntax `clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX)` and is equivalent to `max(MIN, min(VAL, MAX))`.

`min()` and `max()` may be nested. They can be used in `calc()` as well as outside of it, they also may contain math expressions, that means you can avoid `calc()` when using them.

Therefore the original example can be written as:

```
max-width: max(500px, 100% - 80px);
```

Comment: For what it's worth, MS Edge for macOS (Version 81.0.416.68) also allows these. One would assume the Windows version also works. Don't know the min supported version.

Comment: The new Edge is essentially Chrome, its versions follow that of Chrome. Full browser compatibility data is [at the end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min#Browser_compatibility) of the linked pages.

Comment: Someone, give this guy some award

Answer (score 128):

A 'pure' css solution actually is possible now using media queries:

```
.yourselector {
  max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .yourselector {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! I've used it actually for min height, apparently you may use media queries for `max-height` as well +1

Comment: That's a basic workaround, it won't work if the css rule is to be applied to an element rather than the whole screen.

Answer (score 105):

No you cannot. `max()` and `min()` have been dropped from CSS3 Values and Units. They may be [re-introduced in CSS4 Values and Units](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/203) however. There is currently no spec for them, and the `calc()` spec does not mention that either are valid inside a `calc()` function.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an alternative in order to have the same result ?

Comment: You can use JavaScript to get the computed style (actually the used style) of the element. Remove 80px from it and compare it to 500 to see which is greater. Something like var val = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue("width")) - 80 ) for getting the width - 80 and el.style.maxWidth for setting the max-width.

Comment: Thank you. However, I would prefer a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Anytime there is a CSS question and a response begins with "You can use JavaScript", it's incorrect.  There are many valid reasons for wanting to keep all presentation code in CSS.  All-- not most.

Comment: It seems like min() and max() are back in CSS Values and Units Module Level 4  (Editor’s Draft, 1 September 2017)
Link: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#calc-notation

Comment: BUT there is a solution to the problem, keep scrolling to @andy answer below

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't mention it works perfectly in Safari: [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max), [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max#Browser_compatibility). So the answer to "is it possible?" should **not** be: *"No you cannot."* You should always mention browser compatibility in your browser related answers.

Answer (score 46):

A workaround would be to use `width` itself.

```
max-width: 500px;
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but if I understand @Arnaud's question correctly, he wants the max-width of either `500px` or `100% - 80px`. Your solution limits the max-width to `500px` even if `100% - 80px` is larger.

Comment: But it's the same as using `min()` therefore maybe helpful to others.

Comment: It seems to me that using min-width instead of max-width in the above example might be an equivalent to the asked-for behavior, though.

Comment: Answer helped me add a margin to a flex container once the page width got small. http://codepen.io/OBS/pen/wGrRJV

Comment: I posted a solution demonstrating @GertSønderby's comment is indeed the correct solution.

Answer (score 14):

While [@david-mangold's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33100964/5411817), was "close" it was incorrect.
(You *can* use his solution if you want a *minimum* width, instead of a *maximum* width).

This solution demonstrates that @gert-sønderby comment to that answer *does* work:
The answer should have used `min-width`, not `max-width`.

This is what it should have said:

```
min-width: 500px;
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

Yes, use **min-width** plus **width** to emulate a **max()** function.

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/SherylHohman/pen/VNPzNo) (easier to see the demo on CodePen, and you can edit it for your own testing).

```css
.parent600, .parent500, .parent400 {
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.parent600 {
    width: 600px;
}
.parent500 {
    width: 500px;
}
.parent400 {
    width: 400px;
}

.parent600 .child, .parent500 .child, .parent400 .child {
    min-width: 500px;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height:60px;
}

.ruler600 {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.width500 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    float: left;
}
.width80 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
}

.parent600 .wrong, .parent500 .wrong, .parent400 .wrong {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:60px;
}
```

```html
<h2>(Min) min-width correctly gives us the Larger dimension: </h2>
<div class="parent600">
    600px parent
    <div class="child">child is max(500px, 600px - 80px) = max(500px, 520px) = 520px</div>
</div>

<div class="ruler600"><div class="width500">500px</div>20<div class="width80">80px</div></div>

<div class="parent500">
    500px parent
    <div class="child">child is max(500px, 500px - 80px) = max(500px, 420px) = 500px</div>
</div>

<div class="ruler600"><div class="width500">500px</div><div class="width80">80px</div></div>

<div class="parent400">
    400px parent (child expands to width of 500px)
    <div class="child">child is max(500px, 400px - 80px) = max(500px, 320px) = 500px</div>
</div>
<div class="ruler600"><div class="width500">500px</div><div class="width80">80px</div></div>


<h2>(Max) max-width <em>incorrectly</em> gives us the Smaller dimension: </h2>
<div class="parent400">
    400px parent
    <div class="wrong">child is min(500px, 400px - 80px) = min(500px, 320px) = 320px</div>
</div>
<div class="ruler600"><div class="width500">500px</div><div class="width80">80px</div></div>

<div class="parent500">
    500px parent
    <div class="wrong">child is min(500px, 500px - 80px) = min(500px, 420px) = 420px</div>
</div>

<div class="ruler600"><div class="width500">500px</div><div class="width80">80px</div></div>

<div class="parent600">
    600px parent
    <div class="wrong">child is min(500px, 600px - 80px) = min(500px, 520px) = 500px</div>
</div>

<div class="ruler600"><div class="width500">500px</div>20<div class="width80">80px</div></div>
```

That said, [@andy's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37600130/5411817) may be easier to reason about, and may be more appropriate in many use cases.

Also note, that *eventually* a `max()` and a `min()` function may be introduced to CSS, but as of April 2019 it is not part of the spec.

- Here you can check for `max()` Browser compatibility:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max#Browser_compatibility.
- Here is the draft of of the proposal:
  https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#comp-func.
  Scroll to the top of the page to see the last revision date (As of today, it was last revised on 5 April 2019).

Comment: Why the downvote?  Everything stated is correct, and all sources have been linked to and credited.

Answer (score 10):

Change `max` to `Max`, you will see the dirty magic

```
max-width: Max(500px, calc(100% - 80px)))
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right. As per this article: https://css-tricks.com/when-sass-and-new-css-features-collide/

_This is because Sass has its ownmin() function, and ignores the CSS min() function._

_The trick here is to remember that Sass is case-sensitive, but CSS isn’t._

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why sass-loader's error isn't more descriptive to suggest this might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Amaud *Is there an alternative in order to have the same result ?*

There is a non-js pure css approach that would achieve similar results. You would need to adjust the parent elements container padding/margin.

```css
.parent {
    padding: 0 50px 0 0;
    width: calc(50%-50px);
    background-color: #000;
}

.parent .child {
    max-width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only supported in dart-sass https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/special-functions#min-and-max.

You can also make use of string interpolation (similar to CSS variables) for this to work outside of dart-sass

```
max-width: #{"max(500px, calc(100% - 80px))"}
```