# Get a minimum value between view high and view width

Tags: sass

I'm fairly new to scss, I'm trying to make a variable that has the minimum value of 10 percent view height and 10 percent view width.

my approach is

> $size = min(10vh, 10vw);

But I would get unit not comparable error.

How would I solve such issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this can't be done.

At transpile time SASS doesn't know what the height and the width of the viewport are gonna be (think about the change of orientation of a tablet). That information is only available on the client device.

This can't be done in CSS either (there is no max or min function), see [Calc of max, or max of calc in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617248/calc-of-max-or-max-of-calc-in-css)