# Is it possible to use both vw and vh in CSS?

Tags: css, viewport-units

When I resize the window width-wise it looks fine, but when adjusting the height, the text does not resize, which in turn creates overflow across the bracket.

```css
#body div[class^="side-"] ol li p.game a {
  color: #000000;
  font: bold .7vw/1 tungsten, sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
}
```

I've tried using `vmin`, but that does not help as the height of the window is almost always smaller than the width. Is it possible to use both `vw` and `vh` so that the window adjusts to both width and height resizing?

Comment: To answer to the question in the title : Yes.

Comment: What is this strange `.7vw/1`?

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617248/calc-of-max-or-max-of-calc-in-css. So vmin would be helpful, but only if you have a 1:1 ratio of vw and vh sizes.

Comment: @Vivick that's the not so strange short hand declaration of `font-size` and `line-height` using `.7vw` for the `font-size` and ´1´ (one of the few unitless properties in CSS) `line-height`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, depending on the specifics of your use case. CSS allows for `aspect-ratio` media queries. This could allow you to have one `vmin` or `vw`/`vh` size for various aspect ratios. A rough example based on yours:

```
html {
  color: #000000;
  font: bold 7vw tungsten, sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  font-size: 20vmin;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 3/1) {
  html {
    color: #00a;
    font-size: 14vmin;
  }
}
```

This should allow you to solve for your concern about aspect ratios: "I've tried using vmin but that does not help as the height of the window is almost always smaller than the width".

Depending on your design, using `vw` when the screen is wide and `vh` when the screen is taller may be better than using the `vmin` shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can see the property word-wrap: break-word ?

Else, you can see :

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) { /* HERE YOUR CODE */ }
```