# Compute max of calc in CSS

Tags: css, sass

I would like to compute the max of

```
font-size: calc(14px + 30 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
```

and

```
font-size: calc(14px + 30 * ((100vh -568px) / 680));
```

I see that CSS3 dropped the `max()` function. How can I achieve this in pure CSS or SCSS?

Comment: SCSS or any other pre-processor cannot help you here since what you need can be evaluated at run-time only, while **pre**-processors do magic only at build-time.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would like to make it screen-size agnostic

Comment: @AndrewMorton media query won't resolve this because we have vh and vw unit .. so it's 2 dimension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calc of max, or max of calc in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617248/calc-of-max-or-max-of-calc-in-css)

Comment: if I'm not mistaken this question/solution uses media queries. I need a pure css solution.

Comment: Yes but in this solution this is the max of a fixed value and a computed value. And I need  the max of two computed values.

Comment: @Louis Then the answer is the same as for question I suggested might be a duplicate: you cannot. It may be possible when CSS4 comes out though.