# min() in withStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I would like to use min() in withStyles.

I have it currently declared like so :

```
maxWidth: "min(700, 90vw)"
```

I've also tried

```
maxWidth: "min('700', '90vw')"
```

Neither of these work.

Does anyone know how to use this feature with material-ui in react?

Thanks

Comment: Can you calculate the value outside of the styles declaration and then declare `maxWidth: calculatedValue`?

Comment: Have you used `min` successfully outside of material-ui? Far as I can tell, it is not supported by browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617248/calc-of-max-or-max-of-calc-in-css) is out-of-date, I don't believe that `min` is supported in CSS. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min) doesn't indicate any browsers that support it.

You can, however, get the same effect using media queries like the following:

```
maxWidth: "90vw",
"@media (min-width: 777px)": {
  maxWidth: 700
}
```

Here's a CodeSandbox demonstrating this:

[image: Edit p3nmw73jxj]

Comment: Thanks... I'd checked the MDN and saw the documentation and just assumed it was supported...