# How to set a minimum value for a calc() value in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there's a way in CSS to set a minimum value for something that is produced by calc(). For example, at the moment I have:

```
left: calc(50% - 500px);
```

However, I don't want this value to ever be negative, so once this value goes negative, it should just always be 0. Is there some sort of functionality for this that I can't find? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your full use case, probably the asnwer is easier than find a that *minimum* (I suspect you are trying to center something)

Comment: Maybe you can work with @media tags so to limit your left calc(). I don't know if there is something like min-left. But can you explain your usage a bit better in the question? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Media queries could be used in some cases... e.g. if the offset parent is the body element then a simle `@media ... (max-width: 500px) { left: 0}`.

Comment: @SalmanA it would be 1000px in this case since it's 50%

Answer (score 2):

As a pure CSS solution, you can not 'set a minimum value' in `calc()` since the function only takes 1 argument [or an array of operations as 1 argument] and performs calculations with `<length>`, `<frequency>`,`<angle>`,`<time>`,`<percentage>`,`<number>`,`<integer>`  [dimension values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#dimensions), at least [as it stands now](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#calc-notation)

Since negative numbers are a possibility and say you wanted to get a min/max between 2 numbers, per your example, between a 'default' and a calculated result, you couldn't use simple elementary arithmetic to find the max.

Thinking out side of the box it would look something like this where `max = (a+b+|a-b|)/2`:

```
div {
    --a: calc(50% - 500px);  
    --b: 0px;
  --apb: calc(var(--a) + var(--b)); 
  --amb: calc(abs(var(--a) - var(--b))); /* this won't work because we need an absolute value here, which you can not get with simple arithmetic */
  --max: calc( (var(--apb) + var(--amb)) / 2); 

  left: var(--max);
}
```

In some cases CSS values have invalid ranges, à la an RGB value. RGB values can not be less than 0 so that `calc()` result set to the RGB values would be considered valid even if the computed calculation was a negative number, but not applied because RGB's have a distinct range. However, this is not the same for dimensions, unless you explicitly throw a division by zero error somewhere in the calculation to force an invalid result, negative numbers are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
left: max(0, 50% - 500px);
```

for more details [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617248/calc-of-max-or-max-of-calc-in-css#:%7E:text=min()%20and%20max()%20may%20be%20nested.,calc()%20when%20using%20them.&text=No%20you%20cannot.,from%20CSS3%20Values%20and%20Units.)

update:

If you exactly need to use calc() to calculate a max value I guess there is no direct process available.